# Access flask.g inside greenlet

Tags: python, flask, gevent, greenlets

I'm using Flask + gevent and want to access the [`flask.g`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.g) application global inside the target function of a greenlet.
 I'm using the [`copy_current_request_context`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.copy_current_request_context) decorator and have a situation pretty similar to example given in the docs:

```
import gevent
from flask import copy_current_request_context, g

@app.route('/')
def index():
    g.user_data = 'foobar'
    g.more_user_data = 'baz'

    @copy_current_request_context
    def do_some_work():
        some_func(g.user_data, g.more_user_data)
        ...  

    gevent.spawn(do_some_work)
    return 'Regular response'
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user_data'
```

I think a new application context is pushed when the request context is copied? I set a trace in the Flask code [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/ctx.py#L317) and that seems to be the case. So the error isn't all that surprising because the `flask.g` object is application context scoped as of 0.10 (see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.app_ctx_globals_class).

Obviously, I can just pass the user data into the target function as arguments:

```
import gevent
from flask import g

@app.route('/')
def index():
    g.user_data = 'foobar'
    g.more_user_data = 'baz'

    def do_some_work(user_data, more_user_data):
        some_func(user_data, more_user_data)
        ...  

    gevent.spawn(do_some_work, g.user_data, g.more_user_data)
    return 'Regular response'
```

And this works just fine, but I was hoping to use `flask.g` if possible.

Comment: When using gevent, did you monkey patch directly after the first import?

Comment: Yea, looks like I left that out of my example. But yes, I'm calling `patch_all` from `gevent.monkey` right away in my actual code.

Comment: To begin with, why do you want to store `user_data` and `more_user_data` in the `flask.g` object? If you need user wise data persistence, there is `flask.session` object. And if you need global persistence, then you can use just about any `module.attribute` to store them.

Comment: The docs seem to indicate that the `flask.g` object is an appropriate place to store user data: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.g

Comment: Also, I do **not** want to persist the user data across multiple requests, so sessions won't be helpful.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#sessions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`flask.g` is [bound with the app context](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.12.2/flask/globals.py#L61), not on request context, [as the doc says](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.g):

> Starting with Flask 0.10 this is stored on the application context and no longer on the request context ...

`copy_current_request_context()` only copy request context, but give you a new app context. You could create one to pass current app context with closure:

```
def copy_current_app_context(f):
    from flask.globals import _app_ctx_stack
    appctx = _app_ctx_stack.top
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        with appctx:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _
```

However, I prefer pass data to greenlet explicitly via arguments, which is cleaner.